# In 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0' Unable to to import import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-api-client

In `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'`

Unable to import import 
`com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places`
Because of this Unable to build `GoogleApiClient` and also unable to use `Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById.`

But in `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'` we can use it properly.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();

Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                if (places.getStatus().isSuccess() && places.getCount() > 0) {
                    final com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + myPlace.getName());
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(myPlace.getLatLng())
                            .title(myPlace.getName().toString())
                            .snippet(myPlace.getAddress().toString()));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPlace.getLatLng()));
                }
                places.release();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the latest versions of Google Play Services, they have broken it up even further, and now you need to include both `location` and `places` in order for the code in the question to compile:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
    //.......
}
```